# Generate the number of partitions of each integer

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, recursion, memory-optimization, memoization

I've coded a program that calculates [the number of partitions of *n* into at least two distinct parts](https://oeis.org/A111133), and is relatively quick too (about N^1.5 complexity). For input 30 000 it takes roughly 4 seconds. The memory usage rises due to its recursive nature (1Gb for 30 000). I need to calculate input that is max 300 000, but can't because of stack overflow. Increasing the stack size unfortunately throws `std::bad_alloc` (I have 16GB of RAM; if anyone can test that it works for 300000 it would be nice). I tried tail recursing it, but couldn't in the end because memoization would become useless.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <chrono>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>                   

std::unordered_map<std::size_t, boost::multiprecision::cpp_int> hmap;

std::size_t hashf(int a, short int b){
    std::size_t seed = 0;
    boost::hash_combine(seed, a);
    boost::hash_combine(seed, b);
    return seed;
}

boost::multiprecision::cpp_int F(int n, short int k, size_t key){

            //skip branches
    if((k == 1 && n > 1) || (k == 1 && n == 1))
        return 1;

    if(k > n || n == 0 || k == 0 || k < 0 || n < 0) 
        return 0;

    {
    auto it = hmap.find(key);
    
    if(it != hmap.end())
        return it->second;
    }

    return hmap[key] = F(n - k, k, hashf(n-k, k)) + F(n-k, k-1, hashf(n-k, k-1));
}


int main(){

    int n;
    boost::multiprecision::cpp_int res = 0; 
    std::cin >> n;

    auto begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for(short int i = 2; i <= (int)std::sqrt(2*n); i++)
        res += F(n, i, hashf(n, i));


    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end - begin);

    std::cout << res;

    printf("\nTime measured: %.6f seconds.\n", elapsed.count() * 1e-9);

    std::cin >> n;

    
    return 0;

}
```

Edit: program is based on [an answer to *How many ways are there to choose non-repeating numbers that add up to N?*](//math.stackexchange.com/a/3065671) on Mathematics SE.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to provide a proper title for the question.

Comment: Edited for better clarification

Comment: I believe the link you actually want is http://oeis.org/A111133.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised to see this, given [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75270596/555045). If it's really about forcefully using recursion, that iterative solution could be rewritten .. though that might be a hack ("forced" recursion of an imperative algorithm, rather than following a recursive definition)

Comment: Your answer helped me alot (mainly showing the fact that it can be done) but the problem requires to build ontop of a recursive solution using dynamic programming. It certainly could be rewritten as recursive but i dont really know how to implement it and memoization with it (viewing the paper did nothing to help me, not to mathematically literate, first time even using combinatorics).

Comment: Bottom-up dynamic programming is also dynamic programming (if anything it's the better kind)

Comment: I'll try to turn it then if all else fails. Just worried that a recursive function implementation would also take too much space but if the original code only takes around 150Mb, then maybe it could work for 300000.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I changed the title so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](/questions/how-to-ask): "*State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it.*". Please check that I haven't misrepresented your code, and correct it if I have.

Answer (score 4):

## Simplify your hash function

If you know the hash key is a combination of a 32-bit integer and a 16-bit integer, you can pack them together in a 64-bit integer and avoid having to create a custom hash function:

```
std::unordered_map<std::uint64_t, boost::multiprecision::cpp_int> hmap;

boost::multiprecision::cpp_int F(std::uint32_t n, std::uint16_t k) {
    // skip branches
    if(k == 1 && n >= 1)
        return 1;

    if(k > n || n <= 0 || k <= 0) 
        return 0;

    // check the cache first
    std::uint64_t key = n | std::uint64_t(k) << 32;

    if(auto it = hmap.find(key); it != hmap.end())
        return it->second;

    // recurse
    return hmap[key] = F(n - k, k) + F(n - k, k - 1);
}
```

This also ensures that the key is guaranteed to be unique, whereas your hash function might cause two distinct pairs of `n` and `k` to be hashed to the same value, which is not what you want! Especially on a 32-bit system, your hash function could likely already have seen collisions for `n = 30000`. You *can* use a custom hash function like that, but then you have to pass it as an extra template parameter to the declaration of `hmap`.

## Avoiding recursion

The on-line encyclopedia of integer sequences lists several different ways to calculate [A111133](https://oeis.org/A111133), some are just sums that can be implemented with a simple `for`-loop without using any recursion. However, these sums might involve very large numbers, which will probably make it slower than the more simple addition of two recursive calls.

Comment: `std::uint_fast64_t` (or `std::uint_least64_t`) is available even on platforms that don't provide `std::uint64_t`.  Almost always a better choice than the exact but optional type.

Answer (score 1):

We can further simplify the recursive function and reduce the total number of requests to our cache like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <cstdint>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

constexpr std::size_t hash(std::uint32_t lhs, std::uint32_t rhs) noexcept {
    static_assert(sizeof(std::size_t) != 64);
    return static_cast<std::size_t>(lhs) << 32 | rhs;
}

using BigInt = boost::multiprecision::cpp_int;

std::unordered_map<std::size_t, BigInt> dp;

BigInt partitions(std::uint32_t n, std::uint32_t k) {
    if (std::uint_fast64_t(k) * (k + 1) / 2 > n)
        return 0;

    if (k == 1)
        return 1;

    auto& value = dp[::hash(n, k)];
    if (value == 0)
        value = partitions(n - k, k) + partitions(n - k, k - 1);
    return value;
}

int main()
{       
    std::uint32_t n = 30000;
    BigInt total = 0;
    for (std::uint32_t k = 2; std::uint_fast64_t(k) * (k + 1) / 2 <= n; ++k)
      total += partitions(n, k);        
    std::cout << total << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

It suffices to verify the condition `k * (k + 1) / 2 <= n` that there exists at least one partition of `n` into `k` distinct natural numbers.

Some rough time estimates:

- `n = 30000` mine:  `3119ms`, yours: `4252ms`;
- `n = 100000` mine: `22228ms`, yours: `35023ms`;
- `n = 300000` mine: `484719ms`. I didn't check your solution because I wasn't sure whether the time and memory requirements scale acceptably.
  Mine required about 12GB at peak and became runnable only after tweaking stack size in the project settings and expanding swap size appropriately.
  But honestly, I didn't wait for my program to finish, only grabbed the computations result.

> I need to calculate input that is max 300 000

> 4210862274208599320132457681361205631766332745531366097251182523840271778374041776996777544268557708791556972634240204931182275636709667458901634960056418648460211352341024814062465102985788332978802711358792090676627722144184552304071441127403307150949156714152542445860792515401696279114099266905863851501599751992437947170596759659111476740607340695732652666851170071652280194048602757002299800991344524743320843401058188959